# page not found when making new url / view Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

**Hello i am trying to add a basic url called localhost:8000/shop**

**so that when i am on my homepage, I can click a link called shop and It will lead me to localhost:8000/shop**

in my urls.py i added

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from homepage import views




urlpatterns = [
    path('' , views.home),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('reviews/' , include('reviews.urls')),
    path('shop/' , include('product.urls')),

]
```

in my folder called product i have a urls.py file with

```
from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('shop/' , views.shop),   
        
]
```

and in my product folder i have a views.py file with

```
from django.shortcuts import render


# Create your views here.

def shop(request):
    return render(request, 'product/shop.html')
```

linking It to my html file inside my product folder..
when i run the server, I get this error message

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/shop
Using the URLconf defined in yorleico.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
reviews/
shop/
The current path, shop, didn't match any of these.
```

**What am i doing wrong?!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To register the path `/shop`, you need to use `path('' , views.shop),` in the urls.py in your shop app. The `/shop` prefix is already being defined by the `path('shop/' , include('product.urls')),` line in your project level urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

All url patterns in the `product` app already start with `shop/`, due to the `path('shop/', include('product.urls'))`. Therefore your `urls.py` for the `products` app should look like:

```
# product/urls.py

from django.urls import include, path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('' , views.shop),   
]
```

otherwise the path should be <s>`/shop/shop/`</s>.

Comment: OMG YOU'RE THE BEST!